# 'None' returned when web scraping using beautiful soup using find()

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, find, python-requests

I am trying to pick the FTSE price from the bbc website using BeautifulSoup & Requests but I get the output 'None' when I run it.

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/topics./c9qdqqkgz27t/ftse-100'
page = requests.get(URL,timeout=5)
#fetch content from URL
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
#parse html content

price =  soup.find(class_='gel-paragon nw-c-md-market-summary_value')
#price = soup.find("div", class_="gel-paragon nw-c-md-market-summary_value")
#find class with name 'gel...'
print(price)
```

I've tried using different types of the find function but both return the same. I plan to use this logic to gather data from multiple pages ultimately but want to get it right before I try to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Your url was wrong, i did few edits and it works!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/topics/c9qdqqkgz27t/ftse-100'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
price =  soup.find('div', attrs={
    'class':'gel-paragon nw-c-md-market-summary__value'})
print(price.text)
```

Output:

```
7442.28
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.bbc.com/news/topics/c9qdqqkgz27t/ftse-100'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
price = soup.select_one('div.gel-paragon')
print(price.text)
```

Output:

```
7418.34
```

Note: Try 'html.parser' if you don't have 'lxml'